# Is an SSD on a Macbook Pro worth it?

Tags: mac, macbook, ssd

I am about to buy a Macbook Pro, specific model unknown yet.

I am very interested in upgrading to an SSD, as I/O latency is extremely important for my work. However, I have no experience with Macbook Pro performance.

Is it worth it? Will the performance be significantly better? What about durability? Any noticeable effect on battery performance?

Comment: Do note that OSX doesn't have TRIM support for SSDs yet, although the 10.6.4 update has given some indication that it might come in the near future.

Comment: @Om Nom Nom For that reason, AnandTech [recommend](http://www.anandtech.com/show/3812/the-ssd-diaries-crucials-realssd-c300/9) SandForce SSDs for Mac users

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I installed an [Intel X25M 80 GB SSD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002IJA1EG) on my MBP about 4 months ago.

Unscientifically, I can say that my boot times went from 50 seconds to about 10, including starting my browser, terminal, mail client, and IDE. No application takes longer that 3 seconds to load.

I would guess that my battery life increased about an hour per charge on average.

I haven't had it long enough to determine if performance degrades, though. It has stayed consistent so far.

Again, nothing scientific, but I love my SSD.

Comment: Cool! How did you install the SSD? The X25 is not officially supported by Apple. Didn't this void your warranty?

Comment: I used the Lifehacker guide at http://lifehacker.com/5541774/how-to-install-a-solid+state-drive-in-your-macbook -- I think if I ever have a problem I'll just swap the old HDD and no one will know the difference ;)

Answer (score 1):

I installed a 240 GB OCZ Agility 2 - A SandForce 1200 Controller Drive - a month ago.

Although the program I used (Carbon Copy Cloner) failed to write to the drive successfully, causing some frustration, I eventually used Disk Utility to image.

After that no problems. Don't worry about no TRIM support in OS X, the drive is fine. Do:

1. turn "noatime" on
2. never use any defragmenting software
3. turn off "safe sleep"

It's taken my drive performance from a stock 5400 rpm HDD from 62 MB/sec to ~270 MB/sec.

Access time for everything is better. Virtual machines run way smoother. Applications launch within 3 seconds.

The drives may not last at this level more than a couple years but I'm stoked so far. You can't go back to platter drives and moving parts after this.